# Slope error after transform?

Tags: regression, t-test, data-transformation

I have a slope $b = 0.9543$ with std err $s_b= 0.1172$ . I compared this to  a theoretical slope $\beta_0 = 2$, which is significantly different  at the level $ p = 0.00044$  (df=4). But what I actually want to know is the p-value for the difference between $1/b$ and $\beta_0 = 0.5$, which comes out as $p= 0.0066$. Am I wrong to think these should be the same? Which one is "correct", bearing in mind that it is the inverse I am interested in?

p values generated with R:

```
pt( (0.9543-2) / 0.1172, 4)
pt( (1/0.9543 - 0.5) / (0.1172/0.9543^2) ,4 ,lower.tail = FALSE)
```

where the reciprocal of the error is calculated by converting to a relative and back again.

Comment: hmm, how did you find the distribution of $\dfrac{1}{\hat{\beta_0}}$? I am not sure if it would be the $t$-distribution again.

Comment: The error of $1/b$ is from usual error propagation. The distribution of that error will not be equivalent, so I don't know if it is acceptable to make a t-test with it. Does this mean that only the first test is valid? The theoretical value of $\beta _0$ is exact.

Comment: You need to show that it has a $t$ distribution for the 2nd test, before you just reverse the test statistic! As far as I can say, the answer is yes, just the first test is valid.